# Debugging neural network dropout problem for the probability not lying inside [0,1]

Tags: python, debugging, neural-network, pytorch, torch

I tried to put a droprate to my neural network (NN) using torch and I got a strange error at the end. How can I fix it?

So the idea is that I wrote a NN inside a function to make it easier to call. The function is the following:
(I personally think the problem lies inside the class of the NN, but for the sake of having a working example I'm putting everything).

```
def train_neural_network(data_train_X, data_train_Y, batch_size, learning_rate, graph = True, dropout = 0.0 ):
  input_size = len(data_test_X.columns)
  hidden_size = 200
  num_classes = 4
  num_epochs = 120
  batch_size = batch_size
  learning_rate = learning_rate

  # The class of NN
  class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_classes, p = dropout):
        super(NeuralNet, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x, p = dropout):
          out = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
          out = F.relu(self.fc2(out))
          out = nn.Dropout(out, p) #drop
          out = self.fc3(out)
          return out

  # Prepare data
  X_train = torch.from_numpy(data_train_X.values).float()
  Y_train = torch.from_numpy(data_train_Y.values).float()

  # Loading data
  train = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(X_train, Y_train)
  train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train, batch_size=batch_size)

  net = NeuralNet(input_size, hidden_size, num_classes)

  # Loss
  criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

  # Optimiser
  optimiser = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

  # Proper training
  total_step = len(train_loader)
  loss_values = []

  for epoch in range(num_epochs+1):
    net.train()

    train_loss = 0.0

    for i, (predictors, results) in enumerate(train_loader, 0):
      # Forward pass
      outputs = net(predictors)
      results = results.long()
      results = results.squeeze_()
      loss = criterion(outputs, results)

      # Backward and optimise
      optimiser.zero_grad()
      loss.backward()
      optimiser.step()

      # Update loss
      train_loss += loss.item()

    loss_values.append(train_loss / batch_size )
  print('Finished Training')

  return net
```

And when I call the function:

```
net = train_neural_network(data_train_X = data_train_X, data_train_Y = data_train_Y, batch_size = batch_size, learning_rate = learning_rate, dropout = 0.1)
```

The error is the following:

```
net = train_neural_network(data_train_X = data_train_X, data_train_Y = data_train_Y, batch_size = batch_size, learning_rate = learning_rate, dropout = 0.1)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/dropout.py in __init__(self, p, inplace)
      8     def __init__(self, p=0.5, inplace=False):
      9         super(_DropoutNd, self).__init__()
---> 10         if p < 0 or p > 1:
     11             raise ValueError("dropout probability has to be between 0 and 1, "
     12                              "but got {}".format(p))

RuntimeError: bool value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous
```

Why do you think there is an error?

Before putting the droprate, everything was working. Additional points for you if you know how to
implement a bias inside my network! For example, on the hidden layer. I can't find any example online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your architecture for this:

```py
class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_classes, p=dropout):
        super(NeuralNet, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=p)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        out = F.relu(self.fc2(out))
        out = self.dropout(self.fc3(out))
        return out
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: So are you transforming p? Why do you need to put that condition? Where is the problem appearing in the definition of my class? I m trying to understand. Thank you so much Nicolas for the help.

Comment: sorry, it appears my previous answer was wrong. try my new edit.

Comment: are you sure we 're dropping the good coefficients ? how could one know ^^' ?

Comment: What are "good" coefficients? All neurons have probability `p` of being zeroed so that's what matters

Comment: sorry, I meant good with respect to the original question which is dropping only coefficients in the hidden layer :)

Comment: You can `self.dropout()` any layer of your choice